# Python Selenium find_element_by_xpath can't find elements

Tags: python, selenium

New to Python and Selenium. Trying to get list of elements that match a xpath or css_selector and extract link text. Searched and tried many variations but everything I've tried returns an empty list. Apparently not using the correct xpath or css_selector values.

Trying to find this element...

```html
<a class="tablelink" onclick="this.blur(); return true;" href="viewoffender.do?method=view&offenderID=0673237&searchLastName=FOSTER&searchFirstName=BEVAN&searchDOBRange=0&listurl=pagelistoffendersearchresults&listpage=1">0673237</a>
```

Have tried all of these...

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('a[href="viewoffender.do"]')
elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("[href='%viewoffender.do']")
elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[contains(@href, "viewoffender.do")]')
elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div[6]/div/table[2]/tbody/tr[3]/td[1]/a")
elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".tableRowEven > td:nth-child(1) > a:nth-child(1)")
elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[starts-with(@id, 'link-viewoffender.do')]")
```

Here is HTML page...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">




<html>


<head>
<noscript>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1; url=javascriptdisabled.html">
</noscript>
</head>
<body>
<base href="https://webapps.doc.state.nc.us/opi/">
<title>NC DPS Offender Public Information</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/DHTMLmessages.js"></script>
<!--<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/contextmenu.js"></script>-->
<script type="text/javascript">
<!-- 
if (screen.width < 1024) {
if (document.all) {
document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/opi800IE.css">');
}
else if (document.getElementById) {
document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/opi800.css">');
}
}
else {
if (document.all) {
document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/opi1024IE.css">');
}
else if (document.getElementById) {
document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/opi1024.css">');
}
}

function showCalendar(dateField) {
if (document.all) {
window.dateField = dateField;
var windowArguments = new Object();
windowArguments.dateField = dateField;  
var sFeatures = "dialogHeight:330px; dialogWidth:250px; help:off; unadorned:yes; status:no; ";
var answer = window.showModalDialog('/opi/calendar.html',windowArguments,sFeatures);
if (typeof(answer) != "undefined") {
dateField.value = answer;
}
}
else if (document.getElementById) {
returnDate(dateField,null);
window.open('/opi/calendar.html','Calendar - Choose a Date','toolbar=0,location=0,status=0,menubar=0,scrollbars=0,resizable=0,width=250px,height=330px');
}
}

var mydate;

function returnDate(dateField, newdate) {
if (dateField != null) {
mydate = dateField;
}
if (newdate != null && mydate != null) {
mydate.value = newdate;
}
}

function displayReport(url) {
if (document.all) {
document.all("reportframe").src = "report.html?url=" + url + "?method=runreport";
}
else if (document.getElementById) {
document.getElementById("reportframe").src = "report.html?url=" + url + "?method=runreport";
}
}
// -->
</script>
<div id="mainpage">

<div id="banner">
<div id="centercontent"><center><br>North Carolina Department Of Public Safety<br>Offender Public Information</center></div>
</div>
<div id="box">
<div id="tabs">
<ul>
<li><a href="offendersearch.do?method=view"><span>Offender Search</span></a></li>
<li><a href="offenderescapesearch.do?method=view"><span>Escapes/Captures</span></a></li>
<li><a href="offenderabscondsearch.do?method=view"><span>Absconders</span></a></li>
<li><a href="offenderreleasesearch.do?method=view"><span>Inmate Releases</span></a></li>
<li><a href="downloads.do?method=view"><span>Downloads</span></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>

<div class="seal">&nbsp;</div>


<div class="help"><a href="help.do"><img src="images/find.ico" border="0" alt="Got Questions?"></a></div>


<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/dragiframe.js"></script>
<div class="titlediv"><center>Offender Search Results</center></div>
<div class="maindiv"><br>
<div class="resultspanel">
<table width="100%" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="5" class="displaytable">
<tr align="center">
<td align="center">
<a href="offendersearch.do?method=review&searchLastName=FOSTER&searchFirstName=BEVAN&searchDOBRange=0" class="actionbutton">Modify Search</a>
<a href="offendersearch.do?method=view" class="actionbutton">New Search</a>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<table  class="resultstable" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
<tr><td width="100%" colspan="9"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tr class="tableRowAction"><td align="left" valign="bottom" class="tableCellAction">2 offenders found, displaying 1 to 2</td>
<td valign="bottom" align="right" class="tableCellAction">
<b>1</b></td>
</tr></table></td></tr>
<tr class="tableRowHeader"><th valign="bottom" width="5%" align="center" class="tableCellHeader"><a href="pagelistoffendersearchresults.do?method=list&searchLastName=FOSTER&searchFirstName=BEVAN&searchDOBRange=0&order=asc&sort=0" class="tableCellHeader">Offender Number</th>
<th valign="bottom" width="10%" align="left" class="tableCellHeader"><a href="pagelistoffendersearchresults.do?method=list&searchLastName=FOSTER&searchFirstName=BEVAN&searchDOBRange=0&order=asc&sort=1" class="tableCellHeader"><br>Last Name</th>
<th valign="bottom" width="5%" align="left" class="tableCellHeader"><a href="pagelistoffendersearchresults.do?method=list&searchLastName=FOSTER&searchFirstName=BEVAN&searchDOBRange=0&order=asc&sort=2" class="tableCellHeader"><br>Name<br>Suffix</th>
<th valign="bottom" width="10%" align="left" class="tableCellHeader"><a href="pagelistoffendersearchresults.do?method=list&searchLastName=FOSTER&searchFirstName=BEVAN&searchDOBRange=0&order=asc&sort=3" class="tableCellHeader"><br>First Name</th>
<th valign="bottom" width="5%" align="left" class="tableCellHeader"><a href="pagelistoffendersearchresults.do?method=list&searchLastName=FOSTER&searchFirstName=BEVAN&searchDOBRange=0&order=asc&sort=4" class="tableCellHeader">Middle Name</th>
<th valign="bottom" width="8%" align="left" class="tableCellHeader"><a href="pagelistoffendersearchresults.do?method=list&searchLastName=FOSTER&searchFirstName=BEVAN&searchDOBRange=0&order=asc&sort=5" class="tableCellHeader"><br>Gender</th>
<th valign="bottom" width="8%" align="left" class="tableCellHeader"><a href="pagelistoffendersearchresults.do?method=list&searchLastName=FOSTER&searchFirstName=BEVAN&searchDOBRange=0&order=asc&sort=6" class="tableCellHeader"><br>Race</th>
<th valign="bottom" width="5%" align="left" class="tableCellHeader"><a href="pagelistoffendersearchresults.do?method=list&searchLastName=FOSTER&searchFirstName=BEVAN&searchDOBRange=0&order=asc&sort=7" class="tableCellHeader"><br>Birth Date</th>
<th valign="bottom" width="5%" align="left" class="tableCellHeader"><a href="pagelistoffendersearchresults.do?method=list&searchLastName=FOSTER&searchFirstName=BEVAN&searchDOBRange=0&order=asc&sort=8" class="tableCellHeader"><br>Age</th>
</tr>
<tr class="tableRowOdd">
<td  class="tablelink" width="5%" align="center" nowrap valign="top"><a class="tablelink" onclick="this.blur(); return true;" href="viewoffender.do?method=view&offenderID=0673237&searchLastName=FOSTER&searchFirstName=BEVAN&searchDOBRange=0&listurl=pagelistoffendersearchresults&listpage=1">0673237</a></td>
<td  class="tableCell" width="10%" align="left" nowrap valign="top">FOSTER              </td>
<td  class="tableCell" width="5%" align="left" nowrap valign="top">   </td>
<td  class="tableCell" width="10%" align="left" nowrap valign="top">BEVAN      </td>
<td  class="tableCell" width="5%" align="left" nowrap valign="top"> </td>
<td  class="tableCell" width="8%" align="left" nowrap valign="top">MALE</td>
<td  class="tableCell" width="8%" align="left" nowrap valign="top">BLACK</td>
<td  class="tableCell" width="5%" align="left" nowrap valign="top">05/02/1977</td>
<td  class="tableCell" width="5%" align="left" nowrap valign="top">43         </td>
</tr>
<tr class="tableRowEven">
<td  class="tablelink" width="5%" align="center" nowrap valign="top"><a class="tablelink" onclick="this.blur(); return true;" href="viewoffender.do?method=view&offenderID=0673237&searchLastName=FOSTER&searchFirstName=BEVAN&searchDOBRange=0&listurl=pagelistoffendersearchresults&listpage=1">0673237</a></td>
<td  class="tableCell" width="10%" align="left" nowrap valign="top">FOSTER              </td>
<td  class="tableCell" width="5%" align="left" nowrap valign="top">   </td>
<td  class="tableCell" width="10%" align="left" nowrap valign="top">BEVAN      </td>
<td  class="tableCell" width="5%" align="left" nowrap valign="top">J</td>
<td  class="tableCell" width="8%" align="left" nowrap valign="top">MALE</td>
<td  class="tableCell" width="8%" align="left" nowrap valign="top">BLACK</td>
<td  class="tableCell" width="5%" align="left" nowrap valign="top">05/02/1977</td>
<td  class="tableCell" width="5%" align="left" nowrap valign="top">43         </td>
</tr>
</table>

</div>
</div>
<div class="bottomdiv">
<table align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1">
<tr>
<td colspan="2">&nbsp;
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="left" valign="top" width="24%">
<a href="http://www.nc.gov"><img src="images/logo_ncgov_110x37.gif" alt="North Carolina - A better place to be, www.nc.gov" width="112" height="40" border="0"></a></td>
<td valign="top" align="left" width="76%">
<span style="white-space:nowrap">
<a class="footerlink" href="privacy.do">Privacy Policy</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<a class="footerlink" href="disclaimer.do">Disclaimer</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<a class="footerlink" href="contact.do">Contact Us</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<a class="footerlink" href="help.do">Help Using This Site</a>
</span>             
<span class="copyright" style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 12px;"><br>&copy 2012 North Carolina Department Of Public Safety. All rights reserved.</span>
</td>
</tr>
</table>


</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please edit the question and add the relevant HTML. While an outside link might be useful now, if it goes dead in the future the question is practically useless. Also, your shared link requires us to request access so it's really not useful at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To identify the element Use any of the following `CSS selector`.

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('a[href^="viewoffender.do"]')
```

**OR**

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('table.resultstable td.tablelink>a.tablelink')
```

**OR**

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('td.tablelink>a.tablelink')
```

---

Once you get the list. you need to iterate.

```
for element in elements:
  print(element.text)
```

Comment: It appears I needed to wait. Added this just before looking for the elements and all the suggestions worked.
driver.implicitly_wait(10)

Thanks for the input everyone

Comment: I ended up using this code instead and no problems...


            element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located( (By.CLASS_NAME, "tableRowHeader")))